# Setting spreadsheetgear CSV delimiter

Tags: spreadsheetgear

How can i set CSV delimeter to ";" semicolon in spreadsheetgear component if possible? We want to set it to semicolon because dutch date format includes commas so the separation does not work well in that case.

I searched SO and Google but couldnt come up with any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear has no APIs to specify the delimiter used for text-based data files, unfortunately.  If you need to read in or write out a file that uses some other delimiter, you would likely need to build your own file reader/writer that parses out the desired delimiter from incoming files or saves outgoing files with the desired delimiter.